# swig namespace error? not a valid base class

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to wrap a C++ library. I am getting an error which I think is related to my use of namespaces but I'm not sure. Unfortunately the documentation for SWIG all seems to focus on in-line documentation and I don't know what it is pulling from my header files.

Here is my .i file:

```
%module cStopPow
%{
    #include "../src/StopPow.h"
    #include "../src/StopPow_SRIM.h"
    #include "../src/StopPow_LP.h"
    #include "../src/StopPow_BetheBloch.h"
%}

%include "cpointer.i"
%pointer_functions(int, intp);
%pointer_functions(float, floatp);

%include "std_vector.i"
#include <vector>
// Instantiate templates
namespace std {
   %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
   %template(FloatVector) vector<float>;
}


%include "std_string.i"
#include <string>
%include "../src/StopPow.h"
%include "../src/StopPow_SRIM.h"
%include "../src/StopPow_LP.h"
%include "../src/StopPow_BetheBloch.h"
```

And here is an cropped example header (they are all pretty similarly defined):

```
#include ...

namespace StopPow
{

class StopPow_BetheBloch : StopPow
{ ...
```

Three of the classes extend StopPow. The library compiles fine under C++ but SWIG gives me the following errors:

```
swig -java -c++ StopPow.i
../src/StopPow_BetheBloch.h:26: Warning 319: No access specifier given for base class 'StopPow' (ignored).
../src/StopPow_SRIM.h:27: Error: 'StopPow' is not a valid base class.
../src/StopPow.h:28: Error: See definition of 'StopPow'.
../src/StopPow_SRIM.h:27: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'StopPow'. Ignored.
../src/StopPow_LP.h:27: Error: 'StopPow' is not a valid base class.
../src/StopPow.h:28: Error: See definition of 'StopPow'.
../src/StopPow_LP.h:27: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'StopPow'. Ignored.
../src/StopPow_BetheBloch.h:26: Error: 'StopPow' is not a valid base class.
../src/StopPow.h:28: Error: See definition of 'StopPow'.
make: *** [StopPow] Error 6
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after much troubleshooting I figured this out. These problems arose after I put my code into a non-std namespace, the above .i file worked when all my code was in std.

There were two problems. First, the base class must be defined in the .i file explicity, which is mentioned in the documentation and I missed. Also, apparently SWIG does not support base classes which have constructors defined. Adding a method StopPow() to the StopPow class causes "Error: 'StopPow' is not a valid base class" for the three classes that inherit from it.

Here is the working StopPow.i:

```
// StopPow.i - SWIG interface
%module cStopPow
%{
    #include "../src/StopPow.h"
    #include "../src/StopPow_SRIM.h"
    #include "../src/StopPow_LP.h"
    #include "../src/StopPow_BetheBloch.h"
%}

%include "cpointer.i"
%pointer_functions(int, intp);
%pointer_functions(float, floatp);

%include "std_vector.i"
#include <vector>
// Instantiate templates
namespace std {
   %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
   %template(FloatVector) vector<float>;
}

%include "std_string.i"
#include <string>

//%nspace StopPow::StopPow;
//%nspace StopPow::StopPow_LP;

// Need to define the base class:
namespace StopPow
{
class StopPow {
public:
    //StopPow();
    virtual float dEdx_MeV_um(float E) = 0;
    virtual float dEdx_MeV_mgcm2(float E) = 0;
    virtual float get_Emin() = 0;
    virtual float get_Emax() = 0;
    float dEdx(float E);
    float Eout(float E, float x);
    float Ein(float E, float x);
    float Thickness(float E1, float E2);
    float get_dx();
    void set_dx(float new_dx);
    int get_mode();
    void set_mode(int new_mode);

    static const float DEFAULT_DX;
    static const float DEFAULT_DRHOR;
    static const int MODE_LENGTH;
    static const int MODE_RHOR;
};
};

%include "../src/StopPow_SRIM.h"
%include "../src/StopPow_LP.h"
%include "../src/StopPow_BetheBloch.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIG handles base classes with constructors/destructors just fine.  The problem is having a namespace with the same name as a class.  Example (for Python):

#### demo.i

```
%module demo

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4127 4100 4211 4701 4706)
%}

%{
#include "demo.h"
%}

%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%template(IntVector) std::vector<int>;
%include "demo.h"
```

#### demo.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace C {
    class A {
    public:
        A() { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
        virtual std::vector<int> func(int a, int b) { return std::vector<int>(a,b); }
        std::string func2() { return std::string("From A"); }
        virtual ~A()  { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
    };
    class B : public A {
    public:
        B() { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
        std::vector<int> func(int a, int b) { return std::vector<int>(b,a); }
        std::string func3() { return std::string("From B"); }
        ~B()  { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
    };
}
```

#### Results

A build and run shows errors during SWIG code generation, but it still compiles successfully.

There are two problems with the result:

- The `B` instance doesn't know about the base class `A`.
- The `B` instance doesn't call its destructor when deleted.

Output:

```
C:\>swig -c++ -python demo.i
demo.h(13) : Error: 'A' is not a valid base class.
demo.h(8) : Error: See definition of 'A'.
demo.h(13) : Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'A'. Ignored.

C:\>cl /EHsc /LD /W4 /MD demo_wrap.cxx /I%PYTHON_ROOT%\include /nologo -link /nologo /LIBPATH:%PYTHON_ROOT%\libs /OUT:_demo.pyd
demo_wrap.cxx
   Creating library demo_wrap.lib and object demo_wrap.exp

C:\>py -3
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import demo
>>> a=demo.A()
__cdecl A::A::A(void)
>>> a.func(3,4)
(4, 4, 4)
>>> a.func2()
'From A'
>>> b=demo.B()
__cdecl A::A::A(void)
__cdecl A::B::B(void)
>>> b.func(3,4)
(3, 3, 3, 3)
>>> b.func2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\demo.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, B, name)
  File ".\demo.py", line 55, in _swig_getattr
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: func2
>>> b.func3()
'From B'
>>> del a
__cdecl A::A::~A(void)
>>> del b
>>>
```

Output after namespace changed to `C`:

```
C:\>swig -c++ -python demo.i

C:\>cl /EHsc /LD /W4 /MD demo_wrap.cxx /I%PYTHON_ROOT%\include /nologo -link /nologo /LIBPATH:%PYTHON_ROOT%\libs /OUT:_demo.pyd
demo_wrap.cxx
   Creating library demo_wrap.lib and object demo_wrap.exp

C:\>py -3
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import demo
>>> a=demo.A()
__cdecl C::A::A(void)
>>> a.func(3,4)
(4, 4, 4)
>>> a.func2()
'From A'
>>> b=demo.B()
__cdecl C::A::A(void)
__cdecl C::B::B(void)
>>> b.func(3,4)
(3, 3, 3, 3)
>>> b.func2()
'From A'
>>> b.func3()
'From B'
>>> del a
__cdecl C::A::~A(void)
>>> del b
__cdecl C::B::~B(void)
__cdecl C::A::~A(void)
```